# Add a column to a dataframe using (extracting unique values) from existing columns

Tags: r

I am new to R, and was not able to search answers for the specific problem I have encountered.

If my dataframe looks like below:

```
d <- data.frame(Name = c("Jon", "Jon", "Jon", "Kel", "Kel", "Kel", "Don", "Don", "Don"),
             No1 = c(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3),
             No2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))

Name No1 No2
Jon   1   1
Jon   2   1
Jon   3   1
Kel   1   2
Kel   1   2
Kel   1   2
Don   3   3
Don   3   3
Don   3   3 
...
```

How would I add be able to add new columns to the dataframe, where the columns would indicate the unique values in column `No1` and `No2`: which would be (1,2,3), (1,2), (3) for John, Kelly, Don, respectively

So, if the new columns are named `ID#`, The desired results should be

```
d2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Jon", "Jon", "Jon", "Kel", "Kel", "Kel", "Don", "Don", "Don"),
          No1 = c(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3),
          No2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
          ID1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3),
          ID2 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA),
          ID3 = c(3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

Name No1 No2 ID1 ID2 ID3
Jon   1   1   1   2   3 
Jon   2   1   1   2   3
Jon   3   1   1   2   3 
Kel   1   2   1   2   NA
Kel   1   2   1   2   NA
Kel   1   2   1   2   NA
Don   3   3   3   NA  NA
Don   3   3   3   NA  NA
Don   3   3   3   NA  NA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

      # evaluate separately for each name
d %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
    # add a column of the unique values pasted together into a string
    mutate(ID = paste(unique(c(No1, No2)), collapse = ' ')) %>% 
    # separate the string into individual columns, filling with NA and converting to numbers
    separate(ID, into = paste0('ID', 1:3), fill = 'right', convert = TRUE)

## Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
## Groups: Name [3]
## 
##     Name   No1   No2   ID1   ID2   ID3
## * <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
## 1    Jon     1     1     1     2     3
## 2    Jon     2     1     1     2     3
## 3    Jon     3     1     1     2     3
## 4    Kel     1     2     1     2    NA
## 5    Kel     1     2     1     2    NA
## 6    Kel     1     2     1     2    NA
## 7    Don     3     3     3    NA    NA
## 8    Don     3     3     3    NA    NA
## 9    Don     3     3     3    NA    NA
```

---

Here's a nice base version with a basic split-apply-combine approach:

```
# store distinct values in No1 and No2
cols <- unique(unlist(d[,-1]))
                           # split No1 and No2 by Name,
ids <- data.frame(t(sapply(split(d[,-1], d$Name), 
                           # find unique values for each split,
                           function(x){y <- unique(unlist(x))
                                       # pad with NAs,
                                       c(y, rep(NA, length(cols) - length(y)))
                           # and return a data.frame
                           }))) 
# fix column names
names(ids) <- paste0('ID', cols)
# turn rownames into column
ids$Name <- rownames(ids)
# join two data.frames on Name columns
merge(d, ids, sort = FALSE)

##   Name No1 No2 ID1 ID2 ID3
## 1  Jon   1   1   1   2   3
## 2  Jon   2   1   1   2   3
## 3  Jon   3   1   1   2   3
## 4  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
## 5  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
## 6  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
## 7  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
## 8  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
## 9  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
```

---

And just for kicks, here's a creative alternate base version that leverages `table` instead of splitting/grouping:

```
# copy d so as not to distort original with factor columns
d_f <- d
# make No* columns factors to ensure similar table structure
d_f[, -1] <- lapply(d[,-1], factor, levels = unique(unlist(d[, -1])))
# make tables of cols, sum to aggregate occurrences, and set as boolean mask for > 0
tab <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(d_f[, -1], table, d_f$Name)) > 0
# replace all TRUE values with values they tabulated
tab <- tab * matrix(as.integer(rownames(tab)), nrow = nrow(tab), ncol = ncol(tab))
# replace 0s with NAs
tab[tab == 0] <- NA
# store column names
cols <- paste0('ID', rownames(tab))
# sort each row, keeping NAs
tab <- data.frame(t(apply(tab, 2, sort, na.last = T)))
# apply stored column names
names(tab) <- cols
# turn rownames into column
tab$Name <- rownames(tab)
# join two data.frames on Name columns
merge(d, tab, sort = FALSE)
```

Results are identical.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(unique_id = paste0(unique(c(No1, No2)), collapse = ",")) %>%
  separate(., unique_id, paste0("id_", 1:max(c(.$No1, .$No2))), fill = "right")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a single external package i.e. `data.table` and get the output.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`), grouped by 'Name', we `unlist` the columns mentioned in the `.SDcols`, get the unique values, and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format, do a join with the original dataset `on` the "Name" column.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(d)[, unique(unlist(.SD)) , Name, .SDcols = No1:No2],
      Name~paste0("ID", rowid(Name)), value.var="V1")[d, on = "Name"]
#   Name ID1 ID2 ID3 No1 No2
#1:  Jon   1   2   3   1   1
#2:  Jon   1   2   3   2   1
#3:  Jon   1   2   3   3   1
#4:  Kel   1   2  NA   1   2
#5:  Kel   1   2  NA   1   2
#6:  Kel   1   2  NA   1   2
#7:  Don   3  NA  NA   3   3
#8:  Don   3  NA  NA   3   3
#9:  Don   3  NA  NA   3   3
```

---

Or this can be done in one-line by first `paste`ing the `unique` elements in 'No1' and 'No2', grouped by 'Name', and then `split` it to three columns by using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(setDT(d)[, ID:= paste(unique(c(No1, No2)), collapse=" ") , Name], "ID", " ")
#   Name No1 No2 ID_1 ID_2 ID_3
#1:  Jon   1   1    1    2    3
#2:  Jon   2   1    1    2    3
#3:  Jon   3   1    1    2    3
#4:  Kel   1   2    1    2   NA
#5:  Kel   1   2    1    2   NA
#6:  Kel   1   2    1    2   NA
#7:  Don   3   3    3   NA   NA
#8:  Don   3   3    3   NA   NA
#9:  Don   3   3    3   NA   NA
```

---

Or using the `baseVerse` just for kicks

```
d1 <- read.table(text=ave(unlist(d[-1]), rep(d$Name, 2), 
      FUN = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=" "))[1:nrow(d)], 
      header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, col.names= paste0("ID", 1:3))
cbind(d, d1)
#  Name No1 No2 ID1 ID2 ID3
#1  Jon   1   1   1   2   3
#2  Jon   2   1   1   2   3
#3  Jon   3   1   1   2   3
#4  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
#5  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
#6  Kel   1   2   1   2  NA
#7  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
#8  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
#9  Don   3   3   3  NA  NA
```

NOTE: No packages used and without much effort in splitting.